# Script to move cell values according to bg colour

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copying

The code below is what I have so far. But for some reason it says I have a next soureRow without for. Any help would be great. I'm trying to get this script to loop through sheets 4 to 10 and if the row has a bg colour of yellow or red and sheet one doesnt have a matching value. to copy the row to the bottom of sheet 1.

```
target = "Sheet1"

For allSheets = 4 To 10

lastTargetRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets(allSheets).Activate
lastCurrentRow = Sheets(allSheets).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For sourceRow = 2 To lastCurrentRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Interior.Color = Yellow Then

        For checkRow = 2 To lastTargetRow
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Value <> Sheets(target).Cells(checkRow, "B").Value Then
            nRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For lCol = 1 To 26       'Copy entire row by looping through 6 columns
                Sheets(target).Cells(nRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(allSheets).Cells(sourceRow, lCol).Value
            Next lCol
            End If

        Next checkRow

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Interior.Color = Red Then

        For checkRow2 = 2 To lastTargetRow
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Value <> Sheets(target).Cells(checkRow, "B").Value Then
            nRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            For lCol = 1 To 26       'Copy entire row by looping through 6 columns
                Sheets(target).Cells(nRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(allSheets).Cells(sourceRow, lCol).Value
            Next lCol

            End If

        Next checkRow2

        End If

Next sourceRow
Next allSheets
```

Comment: You're missing an `End If` on the block beginning `If ActiveSheet.Cells(sourceRow, "B").Interior.Color = Yellow Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you closer:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const TARGET As String = "Sheet1"

    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet, allSheets As Long, nextTargetRow As Long
    Dim shtTmp As Worksheet, lastCurrentRow As Long, sourceRow As Long
    Dim clr As Long, f As Range, bCell As Range

    Dim myYellow As Long            '<<EDIT
    myYellow = RGB(255, 235, 156)

    Set shtTarget = Sheets(TARGET)
    nextTargetRow = shtTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For allSheets = 4 To 10

        Set shtTmp = Sheets(allSheets)
        lastCurrentRow = shtTmp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For sourceRow = 2 To lastCurrentRow
            Set bCell = shtTmp.Cells(sourceRow, "B")
            clr = bCell.Interior.Color 'get the color
            'is yellow or red?
            If clr = myYellow  Or clr = vbRed Then
                'look in colB on Target sheet for the value from source
                Set f = shtTarget.Columns(2).Find(bCell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If f Is Nothing Then
                   'ColB value is not already listed 
                   shtTarget.Cells(nextTargetRow, 1).Resize(1, 26).Value = _
                            shtTmp.Cells(sourceRow, 1).Resize(1, 26).Value
                    nextTargetRow = nextTargetRow + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next sourceRow

    Next allSheets

End Sub
```

Comment: this is awesome but can i make yellow defined as RGB(255, 235, 156)

Comment: thanks that's perfect however it only seems to work with the red colour

Comment: Select a "red" cell and type `? Selection.Interior.Color` in the VB editor Immediate pane and hit enter.  Do you see the same value as when you enter `?  RGB(255, 235, 156)` ?

Comment: never mind im just a noob its working thank you so much, if i wanted to add copy the colour formatting across would that be difficult or do i just select entire sheet and assign colour.

Comment: actually i just got it by adding this code shtTarget.Cells(nextTargetRow, 1).Resize(1, 26).Interior.Color = clrm